# Multiple inheritance from classes 'NSObject' and 'AWSDynamoDBObjectModel'

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create DynamoDB object model class in Swift to represents my table structure and use it to perform CRUD operations.

In the AWSiOSSDKv2 library (my version 2.0.17) changelog there is information to use AWSDynamoDBObjectModel instead of AWSDynamoDBModel.

When my class inherit from NSObject, AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling I receive the following error (my understanding is that in Swift we can inherit from super class only, thus this even make sense...):

> Multiple inheritance from classes 'NSObject' and 'AWSDynamoDBObjectModel'

However, when I inherit only from AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling I recive different error:

```
Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
```

Here is the class:

```
class Test: NSObject, AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling  {
    var hashKeyString: String?
    var rangeKeyString: String?
    var firstAttribute: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! { return "Test" }
    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! { return "hashKeyAttribute" }
    class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String! { return "rangeKeyAtrribute" }
}
```

I am very new in Swift and AWS, I will appreceitate any help as I couldn't find anything on Internet on this problem.

Comment: Some documentation on `AWSDynamoDBObjectModel`, `AWSDynamoDBModeling`, as well as **specifically**, where you are seeing the "Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'" would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem

```
class Test: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling  {
var hashKeyString: String?
var rangeKeyString: String?
var firstAttribute: String?

class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! { return "Test" }
class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! { return "hashKeyAttribute" }
class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String! { return "rangeKeyAtrribute" }

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool { return super.isEqual(object) }
override func `self`() -> Self { return self } }
```

Comment: Maybe say what fixed the problem so others don't need to read every line of code and look for what's different?